# french accents changed to junk characters when saving the SLD in geoserver 2.11.2

Tags: geoserver, java, sld, tomcat, encoding

I have a shapefile with french accent and needs to be published in geoserver 2.11.2. I have my geoserver in tomcat 8.5 and am using Ubuntu 14.04. The french accents are showing fine in get feature info but the issue is only when saving those characters in SLD, the french accents gets changed to junk characters.I have set my encoding as UTF-8 in SLD

[image]

[image]

But when i see the encoding of the file after saving by command `file --mime-encoding` it is in us-ascii instead of UTF-8.

[image]

Comment: please add the actual text of the SLD so we can test with it

Answer (score 1):

I believe the encoding is SLD is ignored, what you need to do is set it in the virtual machine.
See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: I have set this in my Java opts and restarted, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.06, GeoServer 2.10.x & 2.11.2. I upload your SLD using the GUI (and after removing the filters) get a legend with accents:

[image]

`file --mime-encoding data_dir/styles/ian.sld` gives 
`data_dir/styles/ian.sld: utf-8` as expected.

Comment: Do we need to set any specific settings in Ubuntu for setting encoding? For me after uploading SLD file, its showing as us-ascii. I have shared my snpashot

Comment: what is your locale? mine is en_GB.UTF-8 which might help, but no special settings

Comment: When i type locale i am getting below locales
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: my java command is /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/home/ian/Documents/astun/geoserver/geoserver-training/geoserver-2.11.2/data_dir -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar

Comment: I now reinstalled every setup and tried and its working now. I will find the root cause and will update here